# Evaluating the generating function

Tags: calculus, generating-functions

From yesterday I've stucked with the following problem from my class homework

*Find the generating function*
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{n} \cdot x^n
$$

I've tried several different approaches, but none of them worked here. So, I don't know how to even make the first step to solution.

Any hints/ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is it when $k=1?$ $k=2?$

Comment: $k=1$ implies that this is $1/(1-x)$

Comment: $k=2$ implies $1/(1-x)^2$ !!!

Comment: I'll try the induction. Thanks for the idea

Comment: @Sil Yep, you got it right